# jQuery .Validate() submitHandler not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to make a form that when you press the button it will validate, if the validation is successful if will call a function which will do a few things (saving form data to local storage etc).

The problem is I can't get the submitHandler to fire the function. Here is the jsFiddle I've been working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKrawczyk/xdo9nn48/

And the code.

```
<script>
function fireifworked()
{
$('.testIfWorking').html('IT WORKED');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"

        },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
            fireifworked();
        }
    })



    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
    Field 1: <input name="field1" type="text" />
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate"/>
</div>

<div class="testIfWorking">
CHANGE THIS IS WORKING
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try your luck by changing the type of the button to submit.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720354/jquery-validate-submithandler-not-firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button needs to be inside the form and be of type `submit` rathe than `button`

```
<script>
function fireifworked()
{
$('.testIfWorking').html('IT WORKED');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"

        },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
            fireifworked();
        }
    })



    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
    Field 1: <input name="field1" type="text" />
     <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Validate"/>

</form>




<div class="testIfWorking">
CHANGE THIS IS WORKING
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` in the jquery selector is missing, it should be `$('.testIfWorking').html('IT WORKED')`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like jquery is not linked.

Add this in the header before your jquery code starts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There are several ways to start using jQuery on your web site. You can:

-Download the jQuery library from jQuery.com

-Include jQuery from a CDN, like Google as above example.